# Limiting the search window to the current project

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since a few days, VS Code's search window looks into all the disk instead of looking into the directory of the current project. The consequence is that any search now takes 30 minutes... Is it possible to specify a root directory for the search window?

Comment: Speculation: You've explicitly included directories outside the project in the "Files to include" box. Don't do that.

Comment: No, I've never modified this box.

Answer (score 0):

When open new window in vscode select open folder button then find your project folder and select it. Now your search is in project directory.

[Open folder in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMiTC.png)

Comment: I don't see the "Open folder..." command in the Explorer window. I precise I work with remote SSH and the Explorer window only shows my project.